# Delphi Download File with WinInet with UserName and Password

Tags: delphi, wininet, authorize

There are numerous articles of how to download a file using WinInet (that's where I got the code from), but they all seem to be older and/or closed. Downloading without a username and password works fine, but if I protect the folder (Using VodaHost) with username and password I keep getting an authentication error when trying to download a file:

401 Unauthorized......

If I access through a web browser the username/password dialog pops up and I can get in fine.  The folder protected is:

http://www.mywebsite.com/downloads

I have set Server to: www.mywebsite.com and url to http://www.mywebsite.com/downloads.  The username and paswsord has been validated using a web browser.

I have also tried many permutations and am getting a bit frustrated. The 'only' thing I can think of is that it's because the server is not protected, but a folder on the server.  The server cannot be protected because it is/will be publicly accessible. If you need any more info just let me know.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
function Download(Server, Url, User, Pass, FileName : string): boolean;
const
  BUFFERSIZE = 4096;

var
  hSession: HINTERNET;
  hService: HINTERNET;
  hHTTP: HINTERNET;
  lpBuffer: array[0..BufferSize + 1] of Byte;
  BufferLength: DWORD;
  dwBytesRead: DWORD;
  dwSizeOfRq, Reserved, dwByteToRead: DWORD;
  localFile: file;
  fsize: DWORD;

begin
  try
    try
      // Downloads file at URL bypassing cache
      Result := False;

      // Initialize the Win32 Internet functions
      hSession := InternetOpen(PChar('Empyrean'), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0) ;
      // See if the session handle is valid
      if hSession = nil then
        Exit;

      hHTTP := InternetConnect(hSession, PChar(Server), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, PChar(User), PChar(Pass), INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
      if hHTTP = nil then
        Exit;

      // InternetOpenUrl opens a handle to the Internet file using a URL. The flags indicate that the file will always
      // be read from the Internet rather than the cache
      //hService := InternetOpenUrl(hSession, pChar(url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE or INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE or INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
      hService := InternetOpenUrl(hSession, pChar(url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

      // See if the session handle is valid
      if hService = nil then
      begin
        InternetCloseHandle(hService);
        Exit;
      end;

      HttpQueryInfo(hService, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, @dwByteToRead, dwSizeOfRq, Reserved);
      AssignFile(localFile, FileName);
      {$I-}
        Rewrite(localFile, 1);
     {$I+}
     if IOResult <> 0 then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Cannot create local file: ' + FileName);
        InternetCloseHandle(hService);
        Exit;
      end;
      BufferLength := BUFFERSIZE;

      // These three variables will store the size of the file, the size of the HttpQueryInfo content, and the number of bytes read in
      // total. Now determine the length of a file in bytes
      dwByteToRead := 0;
      dwSizeOfRq := 4; // BufferLength
      Reserved := 0;

      // get the file's size.
      if not HttpQueryInfo(hService, HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, @dwByteToRead, dwSizeOfRq, Reserved) then
        dwByteToRead := 0;
      FSize := 0;
      BufferLength := BUFFERSIZE;

      while (BufferLength > 0) do
      begin
      // Read data from the hService handle
        if not InternetReadFile(hService, @lpBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, BufferLength) then
          Break;
        if (BufferLength > 0) and (BufferLength <= BUFFERSIZE) then
          BlockWrite(localFile, lpBuffer, BufferLength);
        fsize := fsize + BufferLength;

      // Check the size of the remaining data. If it is zero, break
        if BufferLength > 0 then
          Result := True;
      end;

      CloseFile(localFile);
      Result := True;
    except

    end;
  finally
    // Close the Internet handle that the application has opened
    InternetCloseHandle(hService);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hHTTP);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Try using a tool like Wireshark to compare the network traffic generated from the browser request with the traffic generated by your program. Or look at the server logs, if you have them. Once you see what's different, you'll have some better idea of what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Are you tried reading the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Tried both and I cannot see where I'm going wrong, ie. I cannot see on either where the UserName and Password are being passed.  I can see the 401 Unauthorized line.  That has largely to do with my inexperience in using WireShark and reviewing Server Logs.

Comment: After reading the MSDN docs you should realise that you need to know which type of authentication is required. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`InternetSetOption()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114.aspx) to specify `INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME` and `INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD` values for the handle returned by `InternetConnect()`, before calling `InternetOpenUrl()`.

Read the documentation for more details:

[Handling Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384220.aspx)

In particular:

> **The InternetOpenUrl and HttpSendRequest functions complete successfully even when authentication is required.** The difference is, the data returned in the header files and InternetReadFile would receive an HTML page informing the user of the status code.

So if `InternetOpenUrl()` is "successful", you will have to use `HttpQueryInfo()` to get the status code, and if it is 401 then set a username/password (prompting the user if needed) and try the request again.  There is an example of that in the above documentation.  The response provides you with the actual file requested only if the status code is 200.

Comment: LebeauThanks, I had put that in (and have done it again) with the same 401 Unauthorized error:  ` InternetSetOption(hHTTP, INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD, pChar(Pass), Length(Pass));
      InternetSetOption(hHTTP, INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME, pChar(User), Length(User));`

Comment: @RRUZ Yes, but I'm no expert. I 'thought' what I'd done was correct, obviously not.

Comment: @David Heffernan I thought, and I could be wrong, that the INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD/USERNAME tells the system that I will be passing strings with username and password.  It isn't in the code shown, but I had tried it and have since tried it again as suggested by Remy to no avail.

Comment: One quick correction to my initial text, the URL was actually set to the filename (which is what it should be I believe) and not just the folder of the file:   `http://www.mywebsite.com/downloads/filetodownload.txt`

Comment: When you use `InternetSetOption()` to set a string value, you have to use `Length()+1` to include the null terminator.

Comment: Many thanks, I will add the +1 to include the null terminator and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for the advice.  I now have the code working by including the username/password in the URL:

```
Server := 'www.myServer.com';
URL := 'http://user:pSassword@www.myserver.com/downloads/filetodownload';
```